# is it possible to have google-auth within django template?

Tags: django, authentication, django-templates, django-authentication, django-allauth

I have a django app that uses Google's allauth for signing up and logging in, but it first takes me to a google url and to sign in, i.e., my header and other parts of my site are not visible. Once I log in through my google account I'm redirected, so the logic works fine.

I'm just wondering if it's possible to have that process be done on my site.

Answer (score 1):

For social auth I prefer to use [Django Social Auth](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html).

In regards to what OP is asking, I've never seen that before and as a user of a system I wouldn't want it like that. Who could grant me that OP wouldn't also be storing other relevant details of mine to perform that operation?

In fact, the idea of social auth is that one is passing the responsibility of authentication to Google or any other provider, hence going to their system to do that operation and then redirected back.